# Ionic 3 send SMS - The keyboard shows inconsistently when preparing to make an invite

Tags: ios, plugins, keyboard, sms, ionic3

When I use the sms plugin with iOS as shown in the Ionic documentation the keyboard shows inconsistently. After calling

```
this.sms.send('416123456', 'Hello world!');
```

as in the documents, one of three things happens without apparent rhyme or reason:

1. The keyboard pops up along with the message as one might expect.
2. No key board or message pops up - the worst outcome. Sometimes the message will appear to pop up for an instant before being pushed down and out of the screen
3. Occasionally the message will rest at the bottom of the screen with no keyboard in the view.

Options 1 and 2 seem to happen almost half the time. When tested, it seems random as repeatedly inviting the same contact will sometimes show things correctly and sometimes not. Further invites thereafter show no patter.

Option 3 is only different in that it happens less often than option 1 and 2.

When option 2 or 3 happen the issue is corrected when the user clicks on the space where the contact's name is located and where you can add additional contacts with the keyboard.